# Unable to get Win 7 on a Dell 5820 precision with Power ISO

Tags: windows-7, dism

Hello we have legacy applications that must be installed on Windows 7 but as the Dell 5820 has NVME drives the operating system cannot see it just after we get to the language selection screen. I have been struggling to make a custom iso using power iso as I have to inject the drivers into the .wim as when I tried to mount the iso power iso just barfs an error saying unable to mount. I have emailed Power iso but they didnt bother to reply. I have also used the DISM function within Power ISO but it doesnt work and I even got an error saying: 'not enough resources to complete the operation.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted
Thanks

Comment: Windows 7 will no longer install on new computers. This has been asked before.   ....    https://superuser.com/questions/1585276/cannot-install-windows-7-in-native-windows-10-machine   ......  Use a Virtual Machine for Windows 7

Comment: If you're trying to slipstream a driver into the ISO, see for example [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows7/comments/112h1xz/how_to_slipstream_nvme_drivers_into_windows_7_iso/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install Windows 7 Pro x64](https://superuser.com/questions/1570593/cannot-install-windows-7-pro-x64)